# Using a function for x value

Tags: javascript, function, highcharts

when using highcharts I have a serie with 2 views. 1 on datetime, 1 on samplenumber, I like to have the point.x value to be a function, so when highcharts grabs x the function is executed and dependent on some scope variable the sample number or date time is returned.

```
$(function () {
  Highcharts.setOptions({                                            // This is for all plots, change Date axis to local timezone
    global : {
      useUTC : false
    }
  });
  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
      renderTo: 'container',
      zoomType: 'xy'
    },

    xAxis: {
      type: 'linear'
    },
    series: [{
      data: [
        {x: calculateX, y:2, z: 4},
        {x: calculateX, y:3, z: 5},
        {x: calculateX, y:4, z: 6}
      ]
    }]

  });
});

var calculateX = function() {
  return this.z
};
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/VrJN2/153/

For now when changing the view i copy all the point.samplenumber or point.datetime values to the point.x property, which works but it is not the preferred solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one change you required.

Write your function inside the script's main function.

```
$(function () {

 // Whole your code 

  var calculateX = function() {
     return this.z
  };
});
```

Here is the fiddle solution : [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VrJN2/154/)